How do I trigger a script to run when data is entered into the cell
I have a Google workbook with multiple copies of the same sheet.  Times are passed to the sheet from a php form. I have a Google App Script that works to change the time format of the 2 time columns.  How do I make the script execute whenever data is entered into the cells.


function myFunction() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange("H5:H").setNumberFormat('h":"mm" "am/pm');
  sheet.getRange("J5:J").setNumberFormat('h":"mm" "am/pm');
}




To execute your Google Apps Script whenever data is entered into specific cells, you need to use an onEdit trigger. This trigger runs automatically whenever the spreadsheet is edited. You can then specify which cells should trigger the script and perform the desired actions.
Set up an onEdit function and check if the edited cells are in the H or J columns from row 5 onward.
Here's the modified script:
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  
  // Check if the edited cell is in columns H or J and from row 5 onwards
  if ((range.getColumn() == 8 || range.getColumn() == 10) && range.getRow() >= 5) {
    formatTimeColumns(sheet);
  }
}

function formatTimeColumns(sheet) {
  sheet.getRange("H5:H").setNumberFormat('h":"mm" "am/pm');
  sheet.getRange("J5:J").setNumberFormat('h":"mm" "am/pm');
}


The sheet data is passed from a php form.  OnEdit() isn't working.  I got onSelectionChange() to work, but I have to enter the cell and move my cursor for it to work.  I am looking for a way to automatically run the code.
